# Changing an Image.Source property in Windows Phone 8 app causes proximity event subscription to stop working

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

Very simple repro app - created a new Windows Phone 8 C# app from template in Visual Studio, added an Image to the content panel, then subscribed for NDEF proximity messages as shown:

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        if (device != null)
        {
            device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", handler);
        }
    }

    private void handler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Received message");
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/test.png", UriKind.Relative));
            });
    }
```

First event works fine (image source is changed successfully). However, after this event has fired once it no longer fires if I touch another NFC tag. If I remove the call to update the image source, it will fire on each touch.

I can't understand why there would be any interaction here. The phone I'm testing on is a Nokia Lumia 620.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark: try to keep reference to your `ProximityDevice` somewhere. Make it a member of the class and assign in constructor.

```
class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ProximityDevice device;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        if (device != null)
        {
            device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", handler);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As it correctly mentioned in comments, this is caused by the Garbage Collector, which collects the instance of the `ProximityDevice`. When `new BitmapImage` is created, memory consumption grows, and this triggers the GC process. That's why you don't have such issue when you don't create the image.

Comment: You're forgetting the explanation for your shot in the dark. Garbage Collection, that is.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be exactly what caused the issue.